# Insufficient memory in "Data Source Configuration Wizard"

Tags: visual-studio, datasource

I try to add new data source for object with "Data Source Configuration Wizard" and get error message: "An unexpected error has occured. Error Message: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program". What is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all what you need manually.

1 Create datasource file, for example Class2.datasource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="Class1" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
    <TypeInfo>WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1, WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

2 Add information about Class2.datasource in project file in `<ItemGroup>` section:

```
<None Include="Properties\DataSources\Class1.datasource" />
```

3 Reload project configuration file

I know, this is a weird solution, but it works!